# R: Benchmark with CPU Usage

Tags: r

I have some functions in R and want to implement a benchmark for both execution time and max CPU consumption during the execution. I'm working on a Ubuntu RStudio Workbench.

It seems like the `mem_alloc` part of `bench::mark` does not represent the CPU usage during execution.
Any ideas how to do so?

Comment: Max CPU load is a strange measure. I don't know how to get that, even just on linux. Maybe use `bench_load_average` somehow? It looks like it utilizes linux `uptime` on a *nix system.

Comment: I have not seen an R benchmark library that includes CPU utilization. Ubuntu has the `System Monitor` application to monitor utilization. In my experience, typical single threaded R functions will use 100% of a single core until the calculation is complete, and parallel processed functions will use 100% of as many cores as were allocated.

Comment: @M.Viking Umm, no. I regularly monitor some heavy R computations with Linux htop. The cores are rarely at 100 % usage.